# What projection to use for many parts of the world

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, rivers

I'm creating a poster which has many separate maps (rivers of the world). I'd like to use a similar projection for each of them, so they're comparable in terms of shape and size. I guess I want some parameterized projection, but which are good candidates, and what parameters to use?

Comment: What means "comparable" for you?

Comment: Is your poster wrapped around a globe?

Comment: @mdsumner: no, it's not.

Comment: My first thoughts would be [WGS84/World Mercator](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-world-mercator/)

Comment: @TsvGis: I thought that because I have several separate maps, it could be possible to use local projections with less distortion than Mercator.

Comment: @Max: That is a good thought. Will you be showing coordinates on the maps?

Comment: @TsvGis: no coordinates.

Comment: @Max: I would go with the suggestion of using local datums if you are not showing coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer rests on what information about world rivers you want to communicate to your audience.

For example, if you're trying to show a difference between the longest rivers in the world, you may want to use a projection with less area distortion. If you're trying to show where significant trade/resource rivers are, locational accuracy would be a priority and area distortion wouldn't matter as much.

Comment: I want to compare the shape and size of the rivers